# How to use a URI in java

Tags: java, uri, skype

Application use: I am creating a connection between a tablet and a desktop. This tablet will send command to my desktop that my java app will then interpret and do accordingly. One of these features I would like to include is controlling Skype. Such as focusing on it. Switching chats. Initiating call. Sending message. ect. But I can't seem get the URI api to work. (This is the only known api that will allow me to initiate calls and chats, so if you know of any other. Please do tell.)

I am not sure If I am doing it right being that this is my first time using a URI ever. This is what I have using

```
import java.net.URI

public void uriTest(){
     try{
          URI uri = URI.create("skype:echo123?call");
     }catch(Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

What am I missing? I know it is probably a lot. Is there some sort of way to implement it. Or when you call .create() does it automatically do it for you?

Any help or clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287103/executing-uri-commands-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code constucted an `URI` and now you have one, nothing more, nothing less. An `URI` is - as the name "Universsal Resource Identifier" says - just an identifier.

What you probably want to do is establish a connection to a location identified by that `URI`. So you need a special identifier, a so-called "Universal Resource Locator" or `URL`:

URL url = new URL("skype:echo123?call");

Still nothing happening since we only defined a location. Next you have to `connect` to it:

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

Now you got an `URLConnection`-object (in this case a `HttpURLConnection`) and you can operate with it: post data, read responses etc. Read up on the API of `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a web application, and deploy it on a web server program such as Tomcat, on your desktop machine. You can then write an app on your tablet which would connect to the server and send commands to the server.

The web application could parse the commands and do something with Skype application running on the desktop.

You would probably write a JSON api and deploy it on the Tomcat server, and then invoke the JSON api from the tablet app.